# Search Server Response for tags in Text file

Tags: python-3.x, html-parsing

I am trying to search am  html for Tags loaded by the user so the amount of tags is variable.
Now i attempted to search the HTML by loading the txt and split the lines but i didnt suceed.

For example this is the Response ([link](http://pastebin.com/aWbPvuGD)):

```
/><div class="cw cx"><span class="cy cz">Rockstar Games Social Club</span></div><div class="da"></div></div></a></a></h3></td></tr></table></div></div><div class="co">
```

And this is the user made tag file that gets loaded ([link](http://pastebin.com/WwT6tFYk)):

```
ABC
Gr
Rockstar Games Social Club
```

Now i want to check the Response for each tag and if i find one i save it in a named txt.
For that i need to assign each line to a string.
But as i load a varying amount of lines i didnt find a solution.
If i had a fixed amount i would use a delimiter for example | and than use data[0] data[1](http://pastebin.com/aWbPvuGD) etc

Comment: Literally i have an html having Text over an href Link
Like <p1>ABC</p1> etc now i loaded a list where the user def tags to search for so fit example line1: BB and in line2 ABC now i load that txt and say If lines in file print found ("ABC") etc

Comment: Updated above the real Response contains more of those tags

Comment: What is the URL you're parsing?